# what is the difference between joomla query syntax

Tags: joomla

what is the difference between joomla query syntax

```
$db->setQuery //and
$db->getQuery
```

I have looked everywhere, but couldn't find where which one should be used and will it make any difference in the following case:

```
$db = FabrikWorker::getDbo(false, 2);
$query = $db->getQuery(true); //if I change $query =$db->setQuery(true);
$query = "SELECT sum(r57.`amount`) AS total_fee
FROM `registration` AS r, registration_57_repeat AS r57
WHERE r.id = r57.parent_id
AND r.id = '{registration___id_raw}'"; 
$db->setQuery($query);
$a = $db->loadResult();
return $a;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The setQuery($query) method sets up a database query for later execution either by the query() method or one of the Load result methods.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "/* some valid sql string */";
$db->setQuery($query);
```

Link to [setQuery docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/1.5#setQuery.28.24query.29)

From the docs of the [getQuery](http://docs.joomla.org/API16%3aJDatabase/getQuery) method:

> Get the current or query, or new JDatabaseQuery object.

So `setQuery` method sets the query for later execution, while `getQuery` returns either new query object or the current query